# Looking for data/event trend analysis and visualization

Tags: logging, analysis, visualization

I have data like this:

Date/Time, Source, EventType

I want a tool to be able to run on this data (I can format it or put it in a database or anything), but I want to be able to see trends - like weekdays, volume by source, relative volume of different sources, etc.

Something easy to use.

I can write my own SQL queries and things like that, but I'm looking for something off the shelf which has good graphs and things so I can spend more time playing with it to learn about the data instead of writing something myself and spend all my time writing the tool.

Answer (score 1):

[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) seems to be the go-to tool for this type of thing. Depending on your log volume, though, it can be expensive.

Comment: It's a small volume - about 300 events a day, just having a hard time visualizing it - want something to make patterns and things obvious.

Answer (score 1):

A free option that seems inspired by Splunk is [Graylog2](http://graylog2.org/). Has various ways of inputting data, such as basic syslog, and does visualization and analysis.

Splunk is definitely more powerful, but expensive for most useful datavolumes. The [free version](http://www.splunk.com/view/free-vs-enterprise/SP-CAAAE8W) allows 500MB/day.

Comment: It's a small volume - about 300 events a day, just having a hard time visualizing it - want something to make patterns and things obvious.

Comment: Then definitely have a look at Splunk Free. Its flexible about the input data and easy to play around with.